# Whatis the difference in this case between doing dw and db?

Tags: assembly, z80

```
value db 0h, 10h

value dw 10h
```

Are they the same? What is the difference?

If I used, for example,

> ld A, (value)

What would happen in both cases?

Comment: you don't have z80 assembler? :-o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
value db 0h, 10h
```

the machine code produced is (hexa bytes): `00 10`

```
value dw 10h
```

the machine code produced is (hexa bytes): `10 00` (because Z80 is little-endian CPU)

`ld A, (value)` will load `A` with value: in first case `0`, and second `16`.

Comment: So am I right to assume that (value) stands for the first byte thatis assigned? Thanks, by the way

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio of course... I mean, `value` is not a "variable", but a label. It doesn't care, if the `db`, `dw` or some instruction follows it, it's like bookmark of \*here\* into memory.  So `(value)` is memory content from that address. How many bytes are used depends, `ld A,(1234)` loads 1 byte, `ld HL,(1234)` loads 2 bytes as word value, both starting at address 1234.

Answer (score 2):

db = data byte = 1 byte

dw = data word = 2 bytes, which are in the little endian order